# Why does java not print inside nested for loops inside a if else statement and appears as terminated?

Tags: java, loops, printing

So, I'm writing a program that returns pyramids when you give a word as an input
for instance:
"Enter a word: "
Hello

Justification (L=left, R=Right)?
L
would print

H

ee

lll

llll

oooo

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Justification{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String word=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Justification (L=left, R=Right)?");
    String Justification=in.nextLine();
    if(Justification.equalsIgnoreCase("l")){
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(word.substring(i,i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }else if(Justification.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
         for (int i = word.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
             for (int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
             for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= i; j--) {

                 System.out.println(word.substring(i,i));
             }
             System.out.println("");
         }
    }else System.out.println("Bad input");
    }}
```

Comment: Step thru with a debugger

Comment: I think the devil is in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-); *"beginIndex - the beginning index, **inclusive**."* and *"endIndex - the ending index, **exclusive**."*

Comment: If you use `String.substring()` for only 1 character, I think you would better use `String.charAt()` instead.

Comment: Also, read about [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `substring(begin,end)` incorrectly. The character at the begin index is included while the character at the end index is not.

If the word is hello, and you call substring(2,4), it would be ll

```
String str = "hello".substring(2,4); //str is "ll"
```

One way to check if substring is used correctly is that **endIndex-beginIndex=length of substring**. In this case, 4-2=2, so the substring should contain 2 characters, which it does.

An easier way to print out the ith character is to use `charAt(i)` instead of `substring(i,i+1);`

```
System.out.println("hello".substring(0,1)); //prints h
System.out.println("hello".charAt(0));      //also prints h
```